# What does "lo" in "(no) lo es" refer to?

Tags: pronombres, clíticos

**English:**

In this sentence, for example:

> El dinero no **lo** es todo en la vida.

What does this "lo" refer to?
Can it be omitted ("El dinero no es todo")?

---

**Español:**

En esta frase, por ejemplo:

> El dinero no **lo** es todo en la vida.

¿A qué se refiere este "lo"?
¿Puede ser omitido ("El dinero no es todo")?

Comment: I know I've read something about adding the direct object pronoun to emphasize or clarify what's being talked about, but I don't remember where...

Comment: "Lo" is a pretty tricky thing in Spanish. It doesn't have a direct counterpart in at least some of the other Romance languages. It's at least sometimes called the "neuter pronoun". If we get some more questions about it, and I bet we will, it will probably warrant a tag of its own.

Comment: Also: which is a more precise translation: "Money is not everything in life" or "Everything in life is not money"?

Comment: @hippietrail Are you thinking about "Ello" and "Esto"? Although "lo" can be the accusative versions of these, here I would say it refers to "todo" and is masculine. Unless you also consider "todo" neuter in some sense.

Comment: @krubo Good question, I think it can be both. In the former case, "lo" in not mandatory, in the latter, it is.

Answer (score 21):

Es una duplicación del complemento directo.

En español culto, cuando el complemento directo o indirecto se antepone al verbo y no es un pronombre, entonces **es obligatorio añadir el pronombre átono** también antepuesto al verbo.

> La tarta **la** llevo yo. (yo llevo la tarta).
>
> La tarta no **la** llevo yo. (yo no llevo la tarta)
>
> A tu hermano **lo** vi en el cine (yo vi a tu hermano en el cine)
>
> A tu hermano no **lo** vie en el cine (yo no vi a tu hermano en el
>   cine)
>
> A mi madre **le** he dicho que ... (yo he dicho a mi madre que ...)
>
> A Pepito **le** han expulsado del colegio (ellos han expulsado a
>   pepito del colegio)
>
> El dinero **lo** consigue todo (todo se consigue con dinero)
>
> El dinero no **lo** es todo (no todo es [se consigue con] dinero)

Comment: [Pronombres personales átonos](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?origen=RAE&lema=pronombres%20personales%20%E1tonos#52), _Diccionario panhispánico de dudas_, sección 5.2.

Comment: We have the same in English for some of those examples, if you want to put the object first: "the quiche, I'll take it", "your brother, I saw him in the cinema", "My mother, I told her that".. It's a bit odd and is generally used in speech rather than writing because you've said the subject before thinking about the rest of the sentence.

Comment: Lo de "español culto" no lo digo yo, lo dice la RAE. A mi no me parece ningún cultismo tal duplicación del complemento pues lo he visto desde pequeño, pero la RAE lo dice así. Para verlo, pincha en el enlace que puso Jaime Soto sobre pronombres personales átonos. En el punto 5 dice esto: «En el español general culto la coaparición del pronombre átono y el complemento tónico responde a las pautas siguientes:» y la pauta reflejada en el punto 5.2 es la que yo resumí para estos foros y modifiqué los ejemplos para que fuera más evidente que eso es lo que ocurre con "el dinero no lo es todo"

Comment: ¡Nunca sabía que ese regla se usaba para complementos directos también! Qué interesante. (Opino también que las respuestas incluyendo algo de la RAE siempre ganan :))

Comment: Actually I didn't know what *español culto* meant. It turns out I only knew the noun sense *cult* for *culto* but it also has an adjective sense *cultured* that is often used with *lengua*, *lenguaje* or the names of languages, such as *español*. So now I understand perfectly (-:

Comment: Aplicar "culto" a las diferentes variaciones de un idioma es una costumbre que se usaba en tiempos de Roma. En la Roma Republicana existían 2 latín diferentes, uno el "latín vulgar" que hablaban los romanos y era un lenguaje "vivo" (evolucionaba) y el "latín culto" que era el lenguaje con el que se escribía y era un idioma rígido y que apenas tuvo cambios con el paso de los siglos. Esta división culto Vs vulgar se hizo mucho más evidente en la Roma Imperial donde el latín vulgar de Hispania era bastante diferente al latín de Judea, y ambos diferentes del latín de Africa, de Italia o Dalmacia.

Comment: Respeusta perfecta Nexus, sucinta y precisa.

Comment: In the only meaningful interpretation of "El dinero lo consigue todo", "El dinero" is the subject and "todo" the object, therefore "lo" is not needed, and the example is irrelevant. Likewise, in "El dinero no lo es todo", if "El dinero" is the subject, the "lo" is not mandatory. So you're not really answering the question.

Comment: This answer is wrong. In *el dinero no lo es todo*, dinero is the subject, not the object. The *lo* agrees with todo.

Comment: This answer is wrong. As guifa says, _dinero_ is the subject. Plus as J.Calleja states on his answer, this sentence has a copulative verb, which means that it can't have a direct object.

Comment: _**La** belleza no **lo** es todo_... Tienen razón, no es la respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 5):

I think this kind of sentence is called in Spanish "oración copulativa". Basically they are composed of:

- Subject
- Verb (normally, to be)
- Attribute

`Dinero` is the subject and `todo en la vida` is the attribute. `lo` is a particle used to emphasize the attribute.

So, `lo` refers to `todo en la vida` and it can be omitted.

For this next part, I am guessing... If somebody disagreed with an affirmative version of the sentence, the conversation might be:

> El dinero es todo en la vida.
>
> No, no lo es.

So, basically, I think the use of `lo` makes the sentence sounds a bit like a reply.

Comment: I have attached the bounty here.  (I would have preferred to get more guidance from the community around this decision, since formal grammar is not my strong suit.)

Answer (score 2):

It is my understanding that "todo" requires the neuter pronoun "lo" when "todo" is not further modified/explained. For example, you could say "Juan lo sabe todo" but not "Juan sabe todo."

However, you can say "Juan sabe todo sobre la jardinería" because "todo" is not left on its own, but is further modified or narrowed to "everything about" a certain subject.

Similarly, "Juan lo come todo" or "Juan come de todo", but not "Juan come todo".

Answer (score 1):

The `lo` in this sentence refers to "todo en la vida".  It's a [direct object pronoun](http://www.studyspanish.com/lessons/iodopro.htm).  The same thing applies for:

> Te lo doy el dinero.

Means:

> I give you the money.

This could also be stated as:

> Te doy el dinero.

Or, assuming that money is already involved in this conversation, you could say

> Te lo doy.

To mean "I give it to you", with "it" referring to the money.

Also, in response to being told "El dinero es todo en la vida", you could say "No lo es!" to mean "No it's not!".

Comment: Any clues as to why we need a direct object pronoun when "el dinero" is already the direct object? Do we always need both? Are them some rules or logic behind it? Does it come across as redundant in Spanish as it appears to an English speaker analysing it?

Comment: @hippietrail: `lo` is not strictly necessary.  Both "te doy el dinero" and "te lo doy el dinero" are correct.  It is redundant, to an extent, yes, but I think it's a stylistic thing.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the `lo` is simply being used expressively to emphasize the speaker's point (and it refers to *todo en la vida*, as another answerer mentioned).

The meaning is almost the same as:

> El dinero no es todo en la vida.

*Money isn't everything in life.*

The extra `lo` gives a feeling similar to this English phrase:

> Money - it's not everything in life.

or

> Money is *not* everything in life.

That, or it could simply be a typo, assumed it's written. The writer may have started with *El dinero no lo es* and changed his/her mind but forgot to delete the `lo`. This is admittedly a long shot, and I think my first suspicion is closer to the truth.

Comment: I'd agree with the stylistic purpose, but this doesn't answer the question of what in the sentence "lo" refers to.

Comment: To do the same in English would require a comma: "Money, it's not everything in life". But I'm not good enough at the peculiarities of "lo" to know about the Spanish usage.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to represent more spoken English, since I would never write anything like that. Even with a comma, it looks tacky.

Edited to answer the part about `lo`.

Answer (score -1):

In this case `lo` refers to `el dinero` as in English you say for example:

> I ate the **cake**.

Or you can say:

> I ate **it**.

In English you say:

> **Money** isn't everything (**It** isn't everything).

Hope you understand my explanation.

Comment: But why is "lo" there when we already have "el" before dinero and "es" implies third person singular doohickey already? In English it's literally "Money **it** isn't everything in life". Is the "lo" optional or mandatory? Is it a kind of ["agreement"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agreement_%28linguistics%29)?

Comment: I think is a [ciclic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clitic).

Comment: @Galled: It's "clitic" actually. But a clitic is just a kind of particle that attaches to other words. That wouldn't explain why it's needed. In fact it doesn't attach in this case so it's not a clitic anyway. It would be a clitic in something like "damelo" however.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with this.

Comment: @Mr.Jefferson: Is it the answer or one or more of the comments to which you object?

Comment: @hippietrail: I don't think the answer is correct.

Comment: In English, we could condense "money isn't everything" into "it isn't everything" assuming context tells us what "it" is.  In Spanish, we'd condense "el dinero no es todo" to "no es todo" because that conjugation of the infinitive `ser` implies literally means "it is".  Spanish verb conjugations are different for I/you/he-she-it/they/we/etc, so we don't need to specify the pronoun.