# Indirect object and "le"

Tags: pronombres, gramática, sintaxis, objetos-indirectos

> La madre le lava la cara a la niña.

In that sentence, why is the word "le" there? The sentence already has a indirect object ("a la niña"), but removing the "le" makes the sentence to sound unnatural.

**Edit**: Does this sentence sound right? Why/why not?

> La madre lava la cara a la niña.

Comment: Maybe the answer by Nexus to [What does “lo” in “(no) lo es” refer to?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/521/157) also applies here.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina intenté cambiar el orden de las palabras de la oración pero no logré encontrar alguna combinación donde el "le" se pudiera omitir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few observations: you have a direct object and an indirect object in your sentence. Just go to the passive voice:

> La cara (de la niña) es lavada por la madre.

So, "la cara" is the direct object. You can now replace the indirect object by "le"

> La cara le es lavada por la madre.

If you omit "le", the subject disappears:

> La cara es lavada por la madre.

so, "le" means "la niña", and can be omited in the original sentence.

From the  [DICCIONARIO PANHISPÁNICO DE DUDAS](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=le%EDsmo)

> d) *Hay verbos que se construyen con complemento directo de cosa e indirecto de persona: El camarero sirvió la cerveza a Pedro; Robaron el bolso a María; El atracador pegó una paliza a la dependienta; El acusado escribió una carta al juez; El médico curó la herida al torero, etc.*

Comment: So in the passive-voice sentence "le" can be omitted. What about the original sentence?

Comment: @dusan You can omit it in the original sentence, as shown in the examples at the bottom of my answer. If you omit it in the passive voice, there is a slight sense change . Edited for clarity.

Comment: @belisarius you're welcome. :)

Comment: Thanks for this @Dr.belisarius ! Does that mean that I could say this? "El acusado le escribió una carta al juez."