# Word usage : te pertenece

Tags: uso-de-palabras

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is the indirect object pronoun required in sentences with an indirect object?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/when-is-the-indirect-object-pronoun-required-in-sentences-with-an-indirect-objec)

> Y solo **te** pertenece a ti.

¿Podemos quitar el "te"? Si no, ¿por qué?

Answer (score 1):

Si el complemento tónico es también un pronombre personal (en este caso "a ti"), la coaparición del pronombre átono es obligatoria, tanto si el complemento es directo como indirecto. Por eso, no se puede quitar el "te".

http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=elLl31yYnD65MTS9uF#51

Answer (score 0):

Es este caso el verbo "pertenecer" se una de manera "reflexiva", por lo que es imprescindible que lleve el artículo "te" delante, de otra manera la frase carece de significado.

Ejemplo y contraejemplos:

> Yo pertenezco a la humanidad. -> Correcto
>   Ese perro te pertenece a ti.  -> Correcto
>
> Yo me pertenezco a la humanidad. -> INCorrecto
>   Ese perro pertenece a ti.        -> InCorrecto.

Espero haber ayudado.

Comment: Bienvenido a Spanish.SE! Esperamos ver tus contribuciones a menudo. Puedes consultar en el [faq] el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: El verbo no es reflexivo. El sujeto (3a persona) es diferente del objeto (2a persona).

Answer (score 0):

El pronombre 'te' debe ser siempre incluido en verbos reflexivos.

En este caso la duda debería recaer en 'a ti', dado que 'te y 'a ti' hacen la misma función.

Este 'a ti' es incluido debido a la connotación de exclusividad que tiene la frase para reafirmar que el objeto únicamente es de una persona.

En otras frases sin esa connotación de exclusividad se utilizaría el 'te' sin el 'a ti', como por ejemplo en la siguiente frase:

'La bicicleta te pertenece'

En este caso como no queremos remarcar que es 'SOLO' le pertenece a él, no es necesario añadir 'a ti'.

En caso de omitir 'a ti' en la frase 'Y solo te pertenece a ti.', la frase tendría un significado totalmente distinto, ya que significaría que el objeto solo te pertenece, pero no hace nada más. En cambio añadiendo 'a ti' se hace referencia a que únicamente le pertenece, pero sin ser excluyente de que el objeto sea o haga algo más.

Comment: El verbo no es reflexivo. El sujeto (3a persona) es diferente del objeto (2a persona).

Comment: Esto es verso. Omitir el ‘a ti’ no cambia totalmente el significado

Answer (score -1):

Y solo te pertenece a ti.

The English version: And you only relates to that you.

It is the word which signifies the meaning of 'relates'.

Comment: I find it really difficult to understand what you mean. Clarify, please?

Comment: Bienvenido a Spanish.SE! We hope to see you here regularly!