# Is Le/Les Required with Gustar and Encantar

Tags: pronombres

I saw an ad that says *Sabores que encantarán a todos*.
[image: Annies-Encantan.jpg]

I thought todos was the indirect object of encantar and therefore required the pronoun even if you also state the indirect object, this case todos, explicitly.

**Can the les be omitted?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is the indirect object pronoun required in sentences with an indirect object?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/when-is-the-indirect-object-pronoun-required-in-sentences-with-an-indirect-objec)

Comment: @pablodf76 If todos is ineeded the indirect object, my understanding is les is required. 
After reading this, I am no longer certain of what I thought I learned 30 years ago: the le/les pronoun is _always_ required when there's an indirect object.
_Sabores que encantan a todos_ sounds wrong to me, but I am not a native speaker.

Comment: It's not common, but it's not wrong. The only (minor) problem of this is that it's ambiguous, since *encantar* can be a conventional transitive verb too. It's highly doubtful that someone could interpret this as if the flavours would put a charm (as in fairies or witches) over people.

Comment: It means: Flavors that will enchant everyone, and therefore does not require les. However, if gustar is used, it will always require a pronoun.

Answer (score 1):

It's a pun, and may not be so easy to catch for all the Spanish speaking countries.

Means both *they'll be charmed by the flavors* and *they will love the flavors*.

Comment: On the face of it your two suggestions are the same. Has something got lost in translation?

Comment: @mdewey, I think the difference is maybe subtle and that Lambie translated one half of it better, but I believe the distinction lies in who is interpreted as the subject/agent, i.e. _flavors that will charm / enchant / put a spell on everybody_ vs. _everybody will love the flavors_. I _think_ (could be wrong) that if _les_ were included in the original phrase, the first interpretation might not work, since in that interpretation _todos_ is a direct object (despite the "personal a", I believe), so if anything would use _los_ (unless maybe this were a case of _leísmo_ or something).