# "No le creo a él o ella". ¿Por qué el pronombre?

Tags: traducción, gramática, pronombres, género, inglés

I don't believe him or her.
No le creo a él o ella.

Seems that in indrect object pronoun is being used, correct?
What is the indirect object here?

Comment: I think this has been addressed at some length in https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/when-is-the-indirect-object-pronoun-required-in-sentences-with-an-indirect-objec?rq=1 If after reading that you still have unresolved queries then perhaps ask a new question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is the indirect object pronoun required in sentences with an indirect object?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/when-is-the-indirect-object-pronoun-required-in-sentences-with-an-indirect-objec)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont believe him or her.

No le creo a él o ella.

---

I dont believe him.

Yo no creo **a él** - Yo no **le** creo. (**indirect object**)

**El** es el destinatario de la acción y será el **objeto indirecto**.

> **He** is the recipient of the action and will be the **indirect object**

---

I dont believe her.

Yo no creo **a ella** - Yo no **la** creo. (**indirect object**)

**Ella** es la destinataria de la acción y será el **objeto indirecto**.

**She** is the recipient of the action and will be the **indirect object**

---

- *El objeto indirecto es la función sintáctica que se le adjudica al destinatario de la acción*.

**¿Quién es el destinatario de la acción?**

> - The indirect object is the syntactic function assigned to the recipient of the action.
>
> Who is the recipient of the action?

---

**Notas Importantes a Recordar** / Important Notes to Remember

- El Objeto indirecto indica la persona o cosa a quien va destinada la acción verbal; suele ir precedido de la preposición "a" o "para".

> - The indirect object indicates the person or thing to whom the verbal action is intended; It is usually preceded by the preposition "a" or
>   "para".

- El objeto indirecto es la función sintáctica que se le adjudica al destinatario de la acción.

> - The indirect object is the syntactic function assigned to the recipient of the action.

- Los pronombres que sustituyen al objeto directo son: me, te, lo, la, nos, os, los, las.

> - The pronouns that replace the direct object are; me, te, lo, la, nos, os, los, las.

- Los que sustituyen al objeto indirecto son: me, te, le, nos, os, les.

> - Those that replace the indirect object are: me, te, le, nos, os, les.

Comment: I **don't believe him**.  I don't know why you write all your answers in English, too. We would just use: Important Reminders.