# When can I use a pronoun in place of a prepositional phrase?

Tags: pronombres, preposiciones, objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos

If I understand correctly, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O47ZY8VoATc) (same one I referenced in [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/41396/mi-hermano-prepara-la-sopa-para-nosotros-is-nosotros-an-indirect-object-an/)) shows an example of replacing a prepositional phrase with a pronoun. It pretty much says that these two sentences are equivalent:

> Mi hermano prepara la sopa para nosotros.

> Mi hermano nos la prepara.

That makes sense to me.

So now I'm trying to understand when I can replace a prepositional phrase with a pronoun, and when I can't. **Can you help me understand this?**

For example, I think the following three sentences are correct:

1. [**En estas circunstancias** la comunidad exige *este derecho*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Inter_American_Yearbook_on_Human_Rights/kvmXEAAAQBAJ).
2. Nado **contra corriente**.
3. Pongo *el librero* **contra aquella pared**.

However, I'm not sure whether the following (or anything similar) are correct. (In fact, they all feel wrong to me.)

1. La comunidad **se** *lo* exige.
2. **Le** nado.
3. **Se** *lo* pongo.

I think that there is a similar issue in English: I can say "I gave a bath to the dog" and "I gave him a bath," and I can say "I lost the battle despite my courage," but I can't say "I lost it [my courage] the battle." In English, I resolve this by looking for "to/for vibes," but I don't know whether that's even correct for English. I mostly rely on habit, and I don't have Spanish habits yet. I don't want to rely on trying to directly translate Spanish prepositions into English; many sources warn me against that!

Comment: I'm afraid your description is slightly off: If you take this: Mi hermano prepara la sopa para nosotros. And then say it's equal in meaning to this: Mi hermano nos la prepara Tou are using direct and indirect objects, there is no prepositional phrase at all, It about substituting indirect and direct object pronouns for nouns. Where did you find those numbered sentences? The substitutions are not quite right. And 2) rewrite does work at all.

Comment: En estas circunstancias la comunidad exige este derecho. Look up the verb exigir in the RAE> Exigir algo a alguien. You can't replace en estas circunstancias. The community demands it in these circumstances. It would just be: La communidad lo exige en estas circunstancias. Remember what I said about reflexive? Exigir here is NOT reflexive. Se exige means: It is required. Se exige camisa en el restaurant. A shirt is required in the restaurant.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks @Lambie! I will try to answer your questions. The first sentence comes from here: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Inter_American_Yearbook_on_Human_Rights/kvmXEAAAQBAJ

Comment: The second sentenceis from here: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Nadar_contra_corriente/2HDGAAAACAAJ?hl=en

Comment: I thought the third sentence was from spanishdict.com, but I can't find it now.

Comment: Yes, I remember what you said about reflexive verbs. In my examples, I was trying to use "le" to replace "en estas circunstancias," and then used "se" in place of "le" because it came right before "lo." If I understand you correctly, that use is not appropriate because it is not correct to replace "en estas circunstancias" with a pronoun. Is that right?

Comment: @Lambie Thanks! I don't quite understand your first point. "You are using direct and indirect objects, there is no prepositional phrase at all, it is about substituting indirect and direct object pronouns for nouns." Can you explain that in a different way? (To me, on the contrary, it seems like the video linked above is indeed replacing a prepositional phrase ("para nosotros") with a pronoun ("nos."))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pienso que ¿Cuándo puedo usar un pronombre en lugar de una frase preposicional? When can I use a pronoun in place of a prepositional phrase?, no es lo mismo que ¿ Cómo combinar los pronombres de objeto directo e indirecto en español?, How to combine direct and indirect object pronouns in Spanish ?, que es lo que aparece en el video.

Tampoco es lo mismo una frase preposicional que un pronombre preposicional.

“Life without **you**"  / "La vida sin **ti**" / "La vida sin **usted**"

[image]

*Por otra parte una frase preposicional es un grupo de palabras que empieza con una preposición y termina en un sustantivo, un pronombre o una frase nominal (el objeto de la preposición). Las frases preposicionales nos dan más información sobre la(s) palabra(s) que describen.*

> On the other hand, a prepositional phrase is a group of words that begins with a
> preposition and ends with a noun, pronoun, or noun phrase (the object
> of the preposition). Prepositional phrases give us more information
> about the word(s) they describe.

"Viven **en** la casa grande" / Pon el jarrón **junto** a la ventana.

"( Ellos) Viven en ella" / " (Tú) Ponlo"

Esto es empezar la casa por el tejado.

Así que entender los ejemplos propuestos no es fácil para alguien que esta en un nivel intermedio de español, ya que no es usual.

- En estas circunstancias la comunidad exige este derecho . La comunidad **Lo exige**
- (Yo) Nado contra corriente . **contra (la) corriente /  (en) contra (la) corriente** / (Yo) **la** (contra-nado)
- (Yo) Pongo el librero contra aquella pared. **lo contra-pongo**

---

Pronombres personales átonos.

Diccionario panhispánico de dudas

https://www.rae.es/dpd/pronombres%20personales%20%C3%A1tonos

**Preposiciones** (25): a, ante, bajo, (cabe), con, contra, de, desde, durante, en, entre, hacia, hasta, mediante, para, por, según, sin, (so), sobre, tras, (versus), (vía).

Además de las formas simples, en la lengua se presentan preposiciones compuestas, como a por, de entre, para con, por entre, por sobre, tras de, etc. y locuciones prepositivas, como a fin de, a pesar de, **junto a**, etc., que expresan los posibles matices del pensamiento.

Comment: Thanks @DIego! I have a questino about your sentence "La comunidad lo exige." 1. I think you are saying that this would be a correct sentence, is that right? 2. If yes to #1, is there a way to add an indirect object pronoun to this sentence in place of "en estas circunstancias"?

Comment: 1. Es correcto. 2 ( En estas circunstancias la comunidad)  En las circunstancias de la comunidad... le exige, le exige a usted, le exige a la administración, le exige al poder político... (este derecho). Gracias a ti!

Comment: In your example "le exige a la administración," I think "le" is there to accompany "a la aministración," correct?

Comment: OK - La comunidad (es la que le) exige a la administración. Le exige a ella.

Comment: I think you are saying that the following sentence is correct: "Lo contra-pongo." (But I could be wrong, maybe you are just describing the structure.) If you are saying that "Lo contra-pongo" is correct, can you recommend a source where I can learn more about sentences like that?

Comment: Contraponer Del lat. contraponĕre. Conjug. c. poner; part. irreg. contrapuesto.

1. tr. Comparar o cotejar algo con otra cosa contraria o diversa. Presente de Indicativo. verbo contraponer 1ª persona "yo contrapongo"

2. tr. Poner una cosa contra otra para estorbarle su efecto. U. t. c. prnl.                         Infinitivo contraponer         
Gerundio contraponiendo
Participio contrapuesto                                                                                   
Conjugación       https://dle.rae.es/contraponer