# "A los problemas del mundo no les doy mucha importancia." -> "No les doy mucha importancia."?

Tags: pronombres, preposiciones, objetos-indirectos

[I asked a native speaker about when I could replace a prepositional phrase with a pronoun.](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnspanish/comments/yy45uq/comment/iwwq9ll/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

If I understood correctly, here is what they told me:

1. Usually, I can only do this when the object of the preposition is a "recipient." Example: "Doné dinero a los refugiados." -> "Les doné dinero."
2. Usually, only living things can be "recipients."

If I understood this correctly, my question is this:
**are there exceptions to these rules? Can you give me some examples? Have I misunderstood these rules?**

For example, are these sentences correct?

- "[A los problemas del mundo no les doy mucha importancia](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2276/when-is-the-indirect-object-pronoun-required-in-sentences-with-an-indirect-objec)." -> "No les doy mucha importancia." (If this is correct, I think it would be an exception to rule #2.)
- "Envié una carta a Paris." -> "Le envié una carta." (If this is correct, I think it would be an exception to rule #2.)
- "Mi hermano robó dinero a nosotros." -> "[Mi hermano nos robó dinero.](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnspanish/comments/yy45uq/comment/iwwq9ll/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)" (This seems like an exception to rule #1, but I guess in this case "nos" is kind of still a recipient. My brother "gave" us "negative money.")
- "Le compré a Juan un regalo para Pedro." -> "Le compré un regalo para Pedro." (If this is correct, this seems like an exception to rule #1, but again maybe Juan is a "negative recipient.")

---

Comment: Please, please stop saying replace a prepositional phrase with a pronoun or provide a clear example here. Hacer algo para alguien. Lo hice para ellos.

Comment: Thanks! My English sentences would be "I "gave money to the refugees." -> "I gave them the money." Does that make sense? If so, I will add it to my question.

Comment: What would you recommend that I say instead of "replace a prepositional phrase with a pronoun"? Maybe I should say "omit a prepositional phrase when an appropriate pronoun is present"?

Comment: The second sentence contains a determiner, not a pronoun. el dinero. No, of course, the "el" in el dinero is not optional. The pronoun would be el dinero: lo.  Like I said, some verbs take prepositions. That does not mean you can take the sentences with prepositions and nouns after them and replace them with pronouns. We have to stop using this forum as a chat. I am going to erase my other comments.

Comment: Do you want me to go to chat? Also, I think you should keep your original comment about how you know what my problem is and verbs taking prepositions. I think that would be useful for other people. Or give it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El Complemento Directo podemos encontrarlo en:

1. Un sintagma nominal - Si se refiere a una cosa o ser inanimado.

- Tu tío compró **cebollas**. - "**Las** compró"
- Dio **el regalo** a su amigo. - "Se **lo** dio"

2. Sintagma Preposicional con "a" - si se refiere a una persona o ser animado.

- Nadie vio a Pedro. - "Nadie lo vio"
- Saludó **a su vecino** en la plaza. "Lo saludó" / "Le saludo" (**Leísmo permitido**)

***En el Esbozo de una nueva gramática de la lengua española (RAE, 1973) se condena el leísmo referido a cosa, pero se permite el referido a persona masculina singular;***

> ***In the Outline of a new grammar of the Spanish language (RAE, 1973) the leísmo referring to a thing is condemned, but the one referring to
> a singular masculine person is allowed;***

Excepciones;

- España venció **a Francia**. "**Le** venció"
- Hemos cazado **un lobo**. "**Le** cazó" / "Lo cazó"
- Busco **un chico**. "**Le** busco / "Lo busco"

---

- "**A los problemas del mundo no les doy mucha importancia"**. - No les doy mucha importancia. - No le doy importancia / No se la doy.
- "**Envié una carta a Paris.**" - (Yo) Envié (a él) una carta a Paris." (Yo) la (carta) envié (a él) - La envié (a él) - La envié.
- "**Mi hermano robó dinero a nosotros.**" -> "Mi hermano nos robó dinero". - Nos lo robo / Nos robo.
- "**Le compré a Juan un regalo para Pedro.**" -> "Le compré un regalo para Pedro." - "Se lo compré" - **Le** / Lo compre (**Leísmo admitido**).

Cuando se refiere a **una cosa o ser inanimado**, **la pregunta** al verbo es **¿qué?** y se cambia por lo, la, los, las. También puede sustituirse por Eso/Esas cosas.

Pedro pinta **un cuadro** - Pedro **lo** pinta, Pedro pinta **eso**.

Cuando se refiere a una persona se pregunta al verbo **¿a quién o a quiénes?** y se cambia igualmente por **lo**, **la**, **los**, **las**. Ahora bien. en masculino y singular (únicamente en estos casos) puede ser sustituido por "**le**" (leísmo permitido por la RAE), por lo que en estos casos "**le**" no sería complemento indirecto sino Complemento Directo CD.

- Él saludó **a Juan** - Él lo saluda (**Leísmo permitido**) Él le saluda.
- Él saluda **a María** - Él **la** saluda.
- Él saludó **a tus primos** - Él **los** saludó.
- Él saludó **a tus primas** - Él **las** saludó.

---

- "Le he dado el café **a tu** novio".

Los pronombres personales tónicos preposicionales se utilizan con la preposición "a", tienen el valor de CI

- Conozco a tu amigo." = "Lo conozco." / "Le conozco" (**Leísmo permitido**)

---

*Se condena el leísmo referido a cosa, pero se permite el referido a persona masculina singular; el leísmo plural siempre ha sido censurado por la Academia, ya que su baja incidencia desde los textos castellanos más antiguos atestigua que tampoco lo ha sancionado nunca mayoritariamente el uso de los hablantes cultos.*

> Leísmo referring to a thing is condemned, but that referring to a
> singular masculine person is allowed; Plural leísmo has always been
> censured by the Academy, since its low incidence from the oldest
> Castilian texts attests that the use of educated speakers has never
> sanctioned it in the main.

Answer (score 1):

I've been going back and forth with [Lambie](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/19182/lambie). They have given me a lot of useful comments and I recommend that they post an answer based on those comments. **If they do that, I will mark it as the answer.**

In the meantime, I am going to try to express what Lambie said in my own words. I think it will be too long for a comment, and @Lambie recommended against extended discussion in the comments. **I will not mark this as the answer.**

**My interpretation of Lambie's comments**

- It is misleading to ask about replacing a prepositional phrase with a pronoun.

  - Sometimes you will find two sentences with identical or very similar meaning, with the first identical to the second except for word order, the inclusion of a pronoun, and the omission of a prepositional phrase. Example: a) "Mi hermano prepara la sopa para nosotros." b) "Mi hermano nos la prepara." But there is no general rule that allows for this.
  - In particular, with verbs that require prepositions (such as "depender de"), there is no rule that allows you to replace the prepositional phrase with a pronoun. Example: "Dependo de mi novio." There is no way to replace "de mi novio" with a pronoun. Here is a partial list of example verbs which require prepositions: https://www.lawlessspanish.com/grammar/verbs/verbs-with-prepositions/
- The only rule worth mentioning is the one pertaining to the use of "a" with indirect or direct objects. (**DO NOT TRY TO GENERALIZE THIS TO OTHER PREPOSITIONAL PHRASES.**)

  - Example: a) "He dado el café a tu novio." = "Le he dado el café a tu novio." = "Se lo he dado." The word "se" has "replaced" the phrase "a tu novio." (We would have used "le" instead of "se," except that it comes right before the word "lo" or "la.") You can do this with a phrase like "a tu novio" because it consists of the word "a" followed by an indirect object. ("Le he dado el café a tu novio" is more natural than "He dado el café a tu novio.")
  - You can also do this with a direct object preceded by the personal "a", like in the following example: b) "Conozco a tu amigo." = "Lo conozco."
- It is probably best to look at the [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/) to answer questions like this. Unfortunately, there is no English version.

Answer (score 1):

**Mini guía sobre los Pronombres**.

Los pronombres son las palabras que sustituyen a los nombres ya sean personas, animales, hechos o cosas evitando con ello las repeticiones.

Hay varios tipos de pronombres Personales y no personales. Dentro de los Personales encontramos a; **Tónicos** y **Átonos** que puede incluir a los Reflexivos y recíprocos, los pronombres Demostrativos, Posesivos...

Aquí haremos referencia solo a los Pronombres **Tónicos** y a los **Átonos**.

**PRONOMBRES TÓNICOS**

- **Los Tónicos** o independientes  (de casos nominativo-vocativo y preposicional). Dentro de una oración pueden cumplir las mismas funciones que un sustantivo, así pueden funcionar como sujeto (tú sabrás), atributo (los culpables son ellos) o fin de preposición (mi hermano vendrá con nosotros).

Los pronombres personales **tónicos** pueden ser; **Preposicionales** y **No Preposicionales**

- Aquellos que no están acompañados de una preposición, **No preposicionales**.
- los pronombres personales tónicos no preposicionales tienen un valor que los sitúa antes del verbo a modo de recurso, de manera que destaquen en la oración. Es decir, se refieren a un antecedente de la oración (persona, cosa, etc.) antes mencionado

**NO PREPOSICIONALES**

[image]

*Pronombres Personales Tónicos no preposicionales*

Ejemplos

-**Yo** tengo un perro y **ella** tiene dos tortugas.

- **Yo** soy una persona tranquila, adoro la nieve.
- **Tú** siempre dices que tienes calor.
- **Ella** se quedó mirando la niebla mientras **él** la observaba.
- **Nosotros** estamos a punto de descubrir un planeta con vida.
- **Vosotras** nunca habéis tomado un tranvía.
- **Ellos** viven en otro mundo.

---

- Aquellos que están acompañados de una preposición, **Preposicionales**.

**PREPOSICIONALES**

[image]

- van acompañados de preposición.
- las formas específicas de 1.ª, 2.ª y 3.ª persona del singular (mí, ti y sí) van detrás de preposiciones ( ejemplo: a mí, para ti …);
- cuando en la **misma oración** aparecen el **pronombre tónico** preposicional y el **pronombre átono** a la vez, ocurre una reduplicación de pronombres. Los tónicos no pueden ir aislados. A mí me gustan los gatos.
- Cuando las formas **mí**, **ti** y **sí** están precedidas de la preposición **con**, cambian a; **con**mi**go**, **con**ti**go** y **con**si**go**.
- los pronombres personales tónicos preposicionales se utilizan con la preposición a, tienen el valor de **CI** y representan al que experimenta la acción del verbo, (Esto me pasa solo **a mí**.) o al destinatario, destino o meta (Te lo digo **a ti**.). También ayudan a expresar el contraste (**A ti** te gusta la ópera, pero **a mí** los musicales.).

Ejemplos Pronombres Preposicionales, donde las formas específicas van detrás de preposiciones ;

Preposicionales:

- **A mí** me gusta la pesca.
- **A ti** el calor siempre te gustó.
- **A ella** el Sol le parecía hermoso.
- Un planeta con vida sería muy importante **para nosotros**.
- ¿Roberto está **con vosotras**?, pues **conmigo** no está.
- El mundo no es nuestro, es también **de ellos**.

---

**PRONOMBRES ÁTONOS**

- **los átonos**  o clíticos (de casos acusativo y dativo), necesitan acompañar a un verbo. Los pronombres personales átonos son aquellos que **funcionan como complemento verbal no preposicional** o como parte de los verbos pronominales (Ahora me arrepiento (V. arrepentirse)).
- Por su carácter átono, se pronuncian ligados al verbo, con el que forman una unidad acentual.
- Carecen de independencia fónica.
- Se denominan **clíticos** cuando anteceden al verbo Me encanta, lo dijo, se fue.
- Se llaman **proclíticos** cuando siguen al verbo Ayúda**me**, díse**lo**, ve**te**

**En el siguiente cuadro se muestra la distribución de formas y funciones de estos pronombres:**

[image]

**En el Esbozo de una nueva gramática de la lengua española (RAE, 1973) se condena el leísmo referido a cosa, pero se permite el referido a persona masculina singular; el leísmo plural siempre ha sido censurado por la Academia, ya que su baja incidencia desde los textos castellanos más antiguos atestigua que tampoco lo ha sancionado nunca mayoritariamente el uso de los hablantes cultos.**

> A continuación se expone de forma sucinta la norma que rige el empleo
> de estos pronombres:
>
> • Cuando el pronombre desempeña la función de complemento directo,
> deben usarse las formas lo, los para el masculino (singular y plural,
> respectivamente) y la, las para el femenino (singular y plural,
> respectivamente):
>
> ```
>      ¿Has visto a Juan? Sí, lo vi ayer.
>      ¿Has visto a Juan y a los niños? Sí, los he visto en el parque.
>      Compré la medicina y se la di sin que nadie me viera.    
>      ¿Has recogido a las niñas? Sí, las recogí antes de ir al taller.
> ```
>
> [Dada la gran extensión en el uso de los hablantes cultos de ciertas
> zonas de España de la forma le cuando el referente es un hombre, se
> admite, únicamente para el masculino singular, el uso de le en función
> de complemento directo de persona: ¿Has visto a Jorge? Sí, le vi ayer
> en el parque].
>
> • **Cuando el pronombre desempeña la función de complemento indirecto,**
> **deben usarse las formas le, les** (singular y plural, respectivamente),
> con independencia del género de la palabra a la que se refiera el
> pronombre:
>
> ```
>      Le pedí disculpas a mi madre.
>      Le dije a su hermana que viniera.
>      Les di un regalo a los niños.
> ```
>
> A pesar de la aparente simplicidad del sistema, existen casos
> excepcionales o aparentemente excepcionales dentro de la norma, así
> como una enorme variedad en cuanto a los usos efectivos en las
> distintas zonas hispanohablantes. Si se desea información
> pormenorizada, pueden consultarse los artículos leísmo, laísmo y
> loísmo del Diccionario panhispánico de dudas, así como las entradas
> dedicadas a verbos que plantean problemas a los hablantes en cuanto a
> la selección de los pronombres átonos de tercera persona (avisar,
> ayudar, curar, disparar, escribir, llamar, molestar, obedecer, pegar,
> saludar, etc.).

https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/uso-de-los-pronombres-los-las-les-leismo-laismo-loismo

Comment: Thanks @Diego! I will go through this and see what it can tell me about my sentences above.